# Windows phone how to get data from Button.content

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, listbox

I have listbox like this:

```
<ListBox Height="589" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="AllNotesListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" SelectionChanged="AllNotesListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Width="460" Height="150" DoubleTap="Button_DoubleTap">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel Width="460" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="120">
                        <Image Source="/SimpleNote;component/Images/note.png" Width="60" Height="60"></Image>
                        <!-->Code for title looks<-->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="80">
                            <TextBlock Text="Title: "></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>               
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And now in function `Button_DoubleTap` I want to have `title` that is on the button that user clicked. How I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the `Tag` property of the `Button`, like this:

```
<Button Width="460" Height="150" DoubleTap="Button_DoubleTap" Tag="{Binding title}">
```

And then you can read it out in your `Button_DoubleTap` method:

```
var button = (sender as Button);
var title = button.Tag;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
 private void Button_DoubleTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
 {
      ((e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as YourClass).title
 }
```